# Using a variable to change directory

Tags: shell, terminal

I would like to extract the current path in a variable and use it later on in the script

Something like:

```
mypath="$pwd"
```

Later on:

```
cd "$mypath"
```

But I am getting a different directory when doing `ls`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost:

```
 mypath=$PWD
```

This one saves a fork over `mypath=$(pwd)`. While some consider it good practice to always double quote variable assignments, technically it is not needed here, since the shell does not perform *word-splitting* for variable assignments.

PS: Note that you are assigning to `mypath` and then use `myvar`... you should be consistent in your variable naming, otherwise it won't work.